# Does Gmail saves organization structure in user's details?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

My company is using G-suite and I'd like to analyze basic organization structure details like who's my manager? or who do I manage?

Is this possible using the GoogleApis?

Thanks,

Aubrey

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely consult this information, not by using Gmail API, but by using the [G Suite Admin SDK](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory).

Particularly, you may be interested in the following endpoints:

- [Retrieving a user](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#get_user)
- [Retrieving an organizational unit](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-org-units#get_ou)

You may also want to see the [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/python) which will help you set up an application that can retrieve this data. There are many languages supported (you can choose the one you prefer on the left sidebar).